# Console text output blocked, even though it's on another thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a very complex Java program. It works fine. However I want to just print a "Working" animation in the app to let the user know the app is responsive. I have created a simple class with a code like this:

```
public class Working extends Thread {
    private volatile boolean finished = false;
    char[] animationChars = new char[] { '|', '/', '-', '\\' };
    int anim = 0;

    public void finish() {
        finished = true;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while (!finishing) {
                print();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // nothing here...
        }
    }

    private void print() throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 0; i < SLEEP_SECS; i++) {
            System.out.print("\rWorking... " + animationChars[anim++]);
            if (anim == 4)
                anim = 0;
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this, at first it works fine. But as the time passes by, there are some cases in which the animation will stop for a few seconds. I though moving this code to another thread would solve this, but as you can see, it hasn't!

My project accesses databases, runs command-line processes and downloads pages a lot. What is causing this problem? Am I missing something or is Java incapable of handling such a simple task.

Comment: Why not dump the for loop?  You could simply increment the `anim` value, display the text and return to the `run` method...You other work could also be consuming large amounts of the CPU cycles, slowing down all the operations, it could be the system running a GC cycle...

Comment: The code is just simplified. I removed some parts from it. But it just outputs data. My other work is consuming 2% of the CPU and starts with 2GB memory but my app can take up to 15 GB of RAM and it happens seconds after I start it.

Comment: @MadProgrammer This app runs on a server with 24GB of RAM with a powerful CPU. System resources is not an issue. I used JDK's profiler to monitor the app.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that these stops is during a full gc, as the a full gc may stop the world to free up some memory (if you are not using a parellel gc).
You should check the gc log.

Comment: It happens too much to be GC. Also, please read my comments above